# How to run a single useEffect both on re-render and on dependency change?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code,

```js
 const [over, setOver] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
     //some logic
  }, [over]);
```

and I want to be able to run the use effect when the (over) has been changed and also if component props changes as for now the code runs only when over has been changed, similar to

```js
  useEffect(() => {
     //some logic
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One straightforward way to do this is add the props in dependency array

```
  useEffect(() => {
     //some logic
  }, [over,props]);
```

But that is not really a good idea

Go through this once [You might not need an effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect)

Comment: great src, yet when re-rendering happens often and the component it really active then there is no other wat..

Answer (score 3):

Your first code and second are not similar at all. Second one runs once only when the component is mounted (added to the DOM). And first code will run **onComponentMount** and **onOverChange**.

You need to understand react component lifecycle to understand how **useEffect** works.

There are 3 lifecycle events. *onMount*, *onStateChange* and *onUnMount*. The callback function runs when *onMount* or *onStateChange* is triggered. When you use `[]` it means the code will only run when mounted and not on any stateChange event. (Cause there isn't any state available to watch)

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // this will run when component is added to the DOM or a dependency state have changed
  console.log("mounted or dependency state changed");
  
  // this will run when component is destroyed
  return () => console.log("component unmounted");
  
}, [dependency1, dependency2]);
```

Comment: What is `onOverStateChange`?

Comment: `Over` is just the name of the variable he used in his code